# PHP - как разделить значение элемента массива?

Tags: php

Допустим есть такой код:

```
$text = array('0' => '*+oleh/');
```

Нужно взять из массива значение "олег", то есть убрать все символы.

Comment: Если убрать все символы,  то ничего не останется. Значение "олег" нету в коде.

Comment: а можно конкретне,вам нужно убрать все символы кроме "Олег"?Если да,то используйте str_replace,или найти в массиве слово Олег?

Comment: $text = array('0' => '*+oleh/','1' => '/sergey+');

Есть массив с такими "нечистыми" значениями,нужно проверить значение на символы ,если есть такие то удалить их и вывести чистые значения в другой массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пройтись по массиву циклом (или подходящей для этого ф-ей), и получить  необходимые подстроки с помощью регулярного выражения. Один из вариантов:

```
$text = ['*+oleh/'];

$text = array_map(function($item) {
    return preg_replace('~[^\w]+~', '', $item);
}, $text);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($text); echo '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => oleh
)
```

Comment: перебор для массива с 1 элементом излишен

Comment: @Alex это универсальный пример.

Comment: $text = array('0' => '*+oleh/','1' => '/sergey+');

Есть массив с такими "нечистыми" значениями,нужно проверить значение на символы ,если есть такие то удалить их и вывести чистые значения в другой массив.

Comment: @igor ну так в чём проблема? Я решение вам написал ещё вчера: [РЕЗУЛЬТАТ РАБОТЫ](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/994087be2ca8ef40efee97868d53caeaec08c3ce)

Comment: Спасибо.Просто хотел вам описать в чем суть то.